# Over-determined least squares with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, math, vector

I want to use OpenCV's least squares SVD algorithm on the scale factor between vectors:

> argmin(λ) Σ_(i ε I) ||vec(a)_i - λvec(b)_i||^2   <--- minimize this error
>
> vec(a)_i = [x_i,y_i,z_i]^T <--- 3D vectors
>
> vec(b)_i = [x_i',y_i',z_i']^T

Each of the n pairs of vectors is known, so there is only one degree of freedom and the system is over-determined. From my knowledge, least squares should find an x that solves `Ax=B`. In this case `A` is the vector:

> [x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2...]

And `B` is the column vector:

> [x_1',y_1',z_1',x_2',y_2',z_2'...]^T

And λ is the vector `[x]`.

So, to have the correct solution in the least square sense, I should use:

```
solve(A, B, lambda, DECOMP_SVD);
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Ransac is an algorythm often emloyed to solve overdetermined systems

Comment: I believe RANSAC is overkill in this case, and I have to be careful with resources, as I am on mobile. My question is more on how to convert the vectors into a valid input for OpenCV.

Comment: Then read the opencv docs. They explain nicely what formt shoul input data have

Comment: Sammy, I know how to use `solve`, but I'm not sure how to get `A`, `B` and `lambda` from the equation. I did read the docs.